# Facebook Graph API - Find page by page id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to find a Facebook page by `page_ID`?

I have a list of Facebook page id's - But I would like to be find and display the actual Facebook page and display some general information about that pages. Is this possible? I would appreciate a quick tutorial and links to other tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible.

You can display any page by just adding the id to the end of the Facebook URL: `http://facebook.com/ID`.

As for general information about the pages, sending a request to `https://graph.facebook.com/ID` will return a JSON object with some basic details about the page. Unless the page owner has set restrictions on the page, no access token is needed.

As for tutorials, the [Graph API pages on the Facebook Developer site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and the [Facebook Graph API explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) are the best places to start.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. 
I Have a database with a number of facebook pages_id(s) and access tokens. I would like to display each facebook page in a list to allow other users to like other pages. But I am unsure how to display the facebook page image, a description and number of likes a page has.

Comment: Hi I can query my database and get all the page_id(s) - But when I add https://graph.facebook.com/ID all I get is https://graph.facebook.com/page_id (xxxxxxxxx)

Comment: What language are you using? If it's PHP you'll need to do a `json_deocde(file_get_contents($url))`. If you're trying to do a bunch of images on a page, you'll probably want to use an FQL query instead of making a bunch of file calls. On this page, any record with a Facebook profile pulls the profile image for that record from Facebook: http://getwellgabby.org/pediatric-cancer-foundations/